# Difference between a rule and a requirement?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between a rule and a requirement? Can these words be used interchangeable in a national standard?

Answer (score 2):

#### [Rule](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rule)

> a principle or regulation governing conduct, action, procedure, arrangement, etc.

#### [Requirement](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/requirement)

> that which is required; a thing demanded or obligatory

---

Rules define things that either must, or must not be done, in order to to ***stay*** within guidelines.

Requirements define things that either must, or must not be done, to ***come*** within guidelines.

Rules are generally *laws* or *regulations* that you must *follow*, while requirements are generally some [*stipulation*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stipulation) that must be *met*. Rules are followed, requirements are met.

> **Examples:**
> You must follow the rule "no running" at the pool or you will be kicked out.
> You must meet the requirement "swimwear required" to be permitted to enter the pool.

***Rules*** must be *followed* to avoid possible punishment, while ***requirements*** must be *met* to be permitted to do some action.

- All *rules* must be followed to stay within guidelines.
- All *requirements* must be met to come within guidelines.
- If one *rule* is broken, you are no longer within guidelines.
- If one *requirement* is not met, you are not within guidelines.
- If one *rule* is followed, nothing changes. You still have to follow each rule.
- If one *requirement* is met, nothing changes. You still have to meet each requirement.

---

The two words are ***not*** directly interchangeable. But, you can change some wording very slightly to exchange the two words and keep the same meaning.

> **Examples:**
>
> *Context:* A class syllabus, possibly.
>
> *Original rule:* You must not cheat on the test, or you will fail.
> *Exchanged:* You must not cheat on the test to be able to pass.
>
> *Explanation -* "No cheating" is a *rule* for the class and it is punishable by failure. It could therefore be considered a *requirement* for passing the class.

This does not mean that you *should* exchange the two words though. Rules are generally used when describing how to maintain eligible status, while requirements are used when describing how to achieve eligible status.